# How to convert puppet hash to another?

Tags: hash, puppet

I have a puppet hash as below

```
$oldHash
{
  server1 => {port1 => {timeout=3}, port2 => {timeout=2}}, 
  server2 => {port1 => {timeout=2}, port2 => {timeout=2}}
}
```

Would like to take out the "timeout=x" part, and get a new hash as below

```
$newHash
{
  server1 => [port1, port2], 
  server2 => [port1,port2]
}
```

I tried this

```
$newHash = $oldHash.map |$server, $ports| {
    {$server =>  keys($ports)}
  }
```

But the newHash becomes

```
[{server1 => [port1, port2]}, {server2 => [port1, port2]}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code you implemented produces an array of hashes. You can convert it to a hash with `Hash.new()`

This code:

```
$new_hash = $old_hash.map |$server, $ports| {
  {$server =>  keys($ports)}
}

notice(Hash.new($new_hash))
```

will output:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): {{server1 => [port1, port2]} => {server2 => [port1, port2]}}
```